# mysql performance & index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have 5 relation tables like

```
ID | FK_USER | FK_POST | DATE
```

Is it faster and efficient to user separate tables for each type of relation, or to create just one table like

```
ID | FK_USER | FK_POST | TYPE | DATE
```

where type is an Enum, and I put an INDEX on TYPE ?

Assume that I search about "subscription" (which is one of my relation types) Is it faster to use separate table and search on it, or use combined table and add "`where TYPE = 1`" to query string?

Comment: Don't suffer from premature optimization, do whichever makes sense.

Comment: but there are 12 millions of rows, does not it change anything in terms of performance

Comment: No. If you use proper indexes, the effect is negligible and it _could_ go in _either_ direction (deeper BTREE +0.1ms, but it's more likely to be cached -10ms or not -0ms ...)

Comment: Index performance depends on cardinality. If you have 12 million records and only a few TYPE values (few hundred), then cardinality is low and you won't improve anything. Also, what @JanDvorak said - do whichever makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have a combined table with a where clause on 'Type'. There will not be much of a difference in performance either way u store the data. But when u have separate tables, in future if you are going to add new type, another table has to be created. This will add upto to your data management headache.